# XSL sort elements depending on attribute with exception of specific elements

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I already have a XSL that sorts my whole Document depending on the attribute values @id or @category. Now i want to enhance it by defining nodes that never should be sorted.

Here is a sample XML:

```
<root>
    [several levels of xml open]

    <elemetsToBeSorted>
        <sortMe id="8" />
        <sortMe id="2" />
        <sortMe id="4" />
    </elemetsToBeSorted>

    <elemetsNOTToBeSorted>
        <dontSortMe id="5" />
        <dontSortMe id="3" />
        <dontSortMe id="2" />
    </elemetsNOTToBeSorted>

    [several levels of xml closing]
</root>
```

This is my XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<!-- Sort all Elements after their id or category -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
            <xsl:sort select="@id" />
            <xsl:sort select="@category" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Next two templates clean up formatting after sorting -->
<xsl:template match="text()[not(string-length(normalize-space()))]" />

<xsl:template match="text()[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xA;&#xD;', '  ')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Ouput:

```
<root>
    [several levels of xml open]

    <elemetsToBeSorted>
        <sortMe id="2" />
        <sortMe id="4" />
        <sortMe id="8" />
    </elemetsToBeSorted>

    <elemetsNOTToBeSorted>
        <dontSortMe id="5" />
        <dontSortMe id="3" />
        <dontSortMe id="2" />
    </elemetsNOTToBeSorted>

    [several levels of xml closing]
</root>
```

How can i achieve that my XSL ignores the "elementsNOTToBeSorted" ?

EDIT:
I have hundreds of elements that should be sorted, but only a few elements (and its childs) that should not be sorted. So logic would be something like "sort all, except a and b"

Comment: Please show your expected output from the sample input?

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- all elements except a few sort their children -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(self::elemetsNOTToBeSorted | self::otherElemetsNOTToBeSorted)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="@id" />
            <xsl:sort select="@category" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ... -->
```

Note that match expression specificity plays a role here. The more specific match expression determines which template will run:

- `node()` is less specific than `*`, so element nodes will be handled by `<xsl:template match="*">`
- elements matching `self::elemetsNOTToBeSorted | self::otherElemetsNOTToBeSorted` will be  handled by the identity template.

Comment: This works but the logic is the other way around. I have like over a hundred elements that should be sorted, but only 2-5 elements that should not be sorted

Comment: And those elements all have different names? That's one indication of XML done wrong. If they represent the same thing, they should have the same name. Is there any way to identify the elements that should be sorted, short of the "just sort everything" approach?

Comment: No, they are all different. With different names, attributes, childs. It's a greater business logic. The xml itself contains about 20000 lines. Nevertheless changing the XML is not an option, neither do i have any power to change it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Tomalak, but when i use the changed answers I am again at the point that everything will be sorted. I am getting the feeling that the match and select attributes do not work as expected. To be sure i switched in eclipse from the "JRE Instance Default" XSLT Processor to "Xalan 2.7.1" but with no effect. I even tried running with only one of the templates activated, which produced the same result: everything was ordered or everything was not ordered.

Comment: @user Last change, see modified answer.

Comment: You could also change `self::` to `ancestor-or-self::` to make sure any descendants of those elements aren't sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line should ignore all descendants elements of elementsNOTToBeSorted:

```
<xsl:template match="elemetsNOTToBeSorted" />
```

if you want these elements still to be present in the output document you can just copy them instead of suppressing:

```
<xsl:template match="elemetsNOTToBeSorted">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This had no effect at all on my output

Comment: That's because there is a typo in your Xml (or my stylesheet) - I used elementsNOTToBeSorted and in the Xml the element is called elemetsNOTToBeSorted (elements does not have n). Once I corrected this it works. I will update my answer to match the name in your xml